# Hyper-v on 2012R2 startup gen1 vm causes the host to freeze up

Tags: hyper-v, host, server-crashes, windows-server-2012-r2

I've searched a lot to resolve the following issue, but nothing helped me.

My problem is, that starting up a first-gen vm locks up the whole host. Only a hard reset helps. Second-gen vm starts and runs perfectly. The freezes happened on 3 different vms. FreeBSD, Ubuntu, Windows Server 2008R2, while Windows 8.1 on second gen config works perfectly. Im using this pc mainly as a workstation.
No eventlog errors nor dumps are generated.

My system:

- Windows Server 2012R2
- FX-8350, non OC
- ASRock 870 Extreme R2 (Crappy    board imho)
- 32GB    DDR3 1866@1600    (My motherboard, against the "support" for 1866ram won't work with full speed)
- 120GB SSD
- 4.5TB Storage space device

I dont think that its due to my system, because vmware workstation was running without problems.

Did I forget to configure something? Any help is appreciated.

---

P.S: Even deactivating C1E, C6, C&Q didnt work.

P.P.S: With no virtual network adapter set, the system still locks up.
Creating a first gen vm without any hdds and network and launching works. Attaching a boot dvd causes the host to freeze.

The host freezes as the gen1 vm begins to boot, doesn't matter if from dvd or hdd

Comment: What is a "first-gen" VM, exactly?

Comment: Hyper-v in Windows server 2012r2 has a new feature, called second-generation vm. The first-gen vm has the same featureset as the versions before

Comment: Try running `sfc /scannow` against the host... sounds a bit like a corrupted installation.

Comment: @ChrisS: The system scan did't find any integrity violations. Also, yesterday, as this problem occured the first time, I had to reinstall the os. I forgot to turn off autobooting the vm, so the host got unusable.

Comment: That's a good one... Maybe Jake will chime in. He's pretty active in the Hyper-V Questions on SF.

Comment: Disabled C1E again and USB3. Still no progress. As soon the vm begins to boot, the system freezes (I can select the boot entry, but after that - total lock up)

Comment: I have to work just now (the work vm, 2008r2 crashes the host...), so I'll remove the hyper-v role and fire up vmware workstation. But I'm still interested in getting hyper-v working. By the way, the same vm works in Hyper-V on a Dell Notebook with an Intel-Cpu!

Comment: Wait. 2012R2 is not really public yet. This could be the same I had when 2008 came out - CRAPPY DRIVERS. Took a generation or two (of the drivers) until the manufacturers had sorted that out ;)

Comment: I don't think I would run anything like this on a "Crappy board imho".

Comment: This would be my next investition. However, I can't explain why hyperv  refuses to work properly while vmware works.

Comment: You didn't have VMware Workstation and Hyper-V installed simultaneously, did you?

Comment: No, i'Ve only hyperv OR vmware installed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it... The reason was the mainboard. It doesnt suprise me anymore that professional software has certified hardware to run on. I was the victim of "it shall run everywhere syndrome".

Bought a high-end ASUS board, now everything works like a charm.